# How can I detect Hyperlink Text Change?

Tags: wpf, hyperlink, richtextbox, textchanged

I have this richtextbox with some hyperlinks, these hyperlinks allows users to change the text of it, and I need to make further actions when the text of it is changed. The hyperlink itself has nothing special, just like below:

```
Hyperlink link = new Hyperlink();
Run run = new Run("haha");
link.Inlines.Add(run);
```

When the users type within the link, I would like to detect that user action and make further moves, something like:

```
link.textchanged += myHandler;
```

So far, I tried to use textBox as the inline of the hyperlink, though it works, but there are so many downsides such as it automatically switch to the next line when there's no enough space.

I also tried to use textrange.changed method, but it did not work.

Thanks!

Comment: All you can handle is the RichTextBox.TextChanged event. You would then have to detect the position of the change to identify if the Hyperlink content has changed. If you need direct feedback, you probably want to control the editing operation. You should use a context menu and an alternative edit button that will popup on mouse over. Then show a TextBox to edit the link. Commit the changes on <Enter> and finally replace content of the original Hyperlink.

Comment: Another alternative to the inline editing is the introduction of an index table (DataGrid) that shows all Hyperlinks contained by the document and allows to edit them. The Hyperlinks in the document must be wrapped into a TextBlock to make the read-only while editing the document.

Comment: TextRange.Changed event is raised when the range changes i.e. the start or end pointer (and not the content "between" those pointers).